# How can I keep 'username' after deleting user in django?

Tags: django

I made a `posts` application and have a `comment` model like this

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

from posts.models import Post


class Comment(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post)

    content = models.CharField(max_length=400)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created_at',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

And I login, and post some comments:
[image]

After I delete user `rightx2`, it becomes `null` or `None`:
[image]

Worse, It changed the `order` of comments, too!

I want to make `username` still there, and keep ordering, too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `models.ForeignKey` to set `author` attribute in `Comment` model, try `CharField`, and add an assignment line in your comment function in `views.py` to let this `Comment.author` attribute equals to its author name every time an `author` create it.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

it was setting `null` because you defined the `author` as `null=True` and `on_delete=models.SET_NULL`, to keep the author id intact you can use `on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING` but as the [doc says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DO_NOTHING)

> you need to manually add the `ON DELETE` constraint into the database
>   field

but to really keep the username here you need to denormalize it and use a separate `username` field which you need to set on saving the comment.

Comment: I understand I have to set another field for storing username. But which one is prefered? `on_delete=models.SET_NULL,` or `on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING` ?

Comment: It depends, in your case I would say using `SET_NULL` with `is_null=True` makes more sense, if you go with `DO_NOTHING` you need to add a `ON DELETE` constraint in the db